# Speed comparison of R and Python implementations

Tags: python, r, performance

I have implemented a specific algorithm in `R`. There exists a `Python` library which offers an alternative implementation.

I would now like to formally compare the speed of the two implementations to assess which is "more efficient" in different kinds of situations.

What would be the best way to do this? [Here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-vs-python-speed-comparison-for-bootstrapping/), it is suggested to use the `system.time()` (in `R`) and `time.time()` (in `Python`) functions to compare the actual executions of the functions. Is this generally recommended? Do these time measures actually measure the same thing?

Would it be an alternative to measure the time of the whole script execution to include "overhead" stuff like variable definitions etc?

PS: I am a regular user of `R`, but have close to zero experience in `Python`

Comment: Why not run both with a real-world test and see which one takes less time?

Comment: Python's got the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#basic-examples) module that is very handy for simple tests from command line.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 My question is how to do this in a somewhat correct way, for example, which functions can I use to do so guaranteeing that they measure the same things

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks for the hint, given my experiences, I only know similar packages for R, but the timeit package looks quite interesting